# phpseclib: how to handle connection error gracefully when instantiating a New_SFTP object

Tags: php, error-handling, sftp, phpseclib

I am trying to handle this connection error in a more graceful way than the default API. The default API will print an error message, but I would like to suppress it and replace it with my own somehow, recognize the error and handle it, but I am not sure how to do so.

```
public function __construct($host)
{
      // trying to test by opening a failed connection -- try catch
      // block doesn't work because no exception thrown
      $this->connection = new Net_SFTP("nonexistent.domain.com");

      // this will not work either ....
      if ( !$this->connection->status_codes )
      {
         throw new Exception("Could not create SFTP connection.\n");
      }

      else
      {
         echo "Connected via SFTP to " . $host . " on port 22.\n";
      }
}
```

Executing it will show that, even though there is an error, it hits the else block:

```
PHP Notice:  Cannot connect to nonexistent.domain.com. Error 0. php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /home/dylan/Documents/php/Net/SSH2.php on line 788
Connected via SFTP to gluon.exavault.com on port 22.
```

I have been looking around at the class in the `Net/SFTP.php` file, but I can't seem to find a way to process the error code and ignore the error message. Does anyone have any ideas on another possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, misread.

You can set `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE)`

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure out how to suppress the error message and that is now working. But I would still like to handle the error on my end as shown above (or another way perhaps using a `try-catch` block). I think I might have to find a way to check the state of the error message from the `Net_SFTP` instance, but so far I am not sure how to do this.